# batch that delete text between two specified points

Tags: windows, batch

I would like do a batch that delete all the text present between `in_point` and `out_point` of `example.txt` like this:

```
bla bla lba aaa uuu
in_point

jhfwjeblwqblf

out_point
bla bla bla
abc cfgr qwerty ecc...
```

The batch has to delete only "jhfwjeblwqblf" (but it's variable, it can be more or less: the batch however have to delete all). How can I do this?

Comment: Not possible in `.bat`, but can be done using PowerShell. Is that ok? And don't you delete the in_point and out_point lines?

Comment: I don't have to delete in_point and out_point

Comment: @harrymc fallible: it **is possible** in a `.bat` providing that the `example.txt` is a plain text file. In any case, Powershell seems to be a better choice…

Comment: that's almost like a dare saying its not possible. I would write it if I had the time to throw at it.